# laravel - vite server refuses to connect

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel project using Vue and Inertia. I am serving the application through Laravel Homestead. When I run `npm run dev` Vite builds the assets, but when I go to the browser I get a blank page. When I open up Chrome devtools, I see this error:

> GET http://blog.test:5173/@vite/client net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> blog.test/:21          GET http://blog.test:5173/resources/js/app.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> blog.test/:21          GET http://blog.test:5173/resources/js/Pages/Blog/Show.vue net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

When I try to go to the app.js file directly, Chrome refuses to connect to the Vite server. When I run `npm run build` everything compiles perfectly. I have checked my Homestead port and the ports are being forwarded. I am not using Docker.

Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.56.56"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: c:\Code\laravel-projects
      to: /home/vagrant/code
      type: "nfs"

sites:
    - map: tyler.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/tyler/public
    - map: begging.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/begging/public
    - map: blog.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/blog/public


databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mysql: true
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

services:
    - enabled:
          - "mysql"
#    - disabled:
#        - "postgresql@11-main"

ports:
     - send: 5173    # change these ports to 5174
       to: 5173
     - send: 33060 # MySQL/MariaDB
       to: 3306
#    - send: 4040
#      to: 4040
#    - send: 54320 # PostgreSQL
#      to: 5432
#    - send: 8025 # Mailhog
#      to: 8025
#    - send: 9600
#      to: 9600
#    - send: 27017
#      to: 27017
```

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'blog.test'
        },
        host: 'blog.test'
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,

                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: sir did you manage to fix your problem? i am having the same problem.